# Reference on constructing preconditions (beginner level)

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I took linear algebra course this semester (as you've probably noticed looking at my previously asked questions!). We had a session on preconditioning, what are they good for and how to construct them for matrices with special properties. It was a really short introduction for such an important research topic, so I'm not sure if I got familiar with them. I need some elementary sources on it to be able to construct preconditions for famous matrices and to make sure I fully understand the concept. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still a very hot topic of Numerical Linear Algebra - The main question is to improve the conditioning of a (usually very large and potentially ill-conditioned) matrix.

Take a look at the work of Dongarra: [Preconditioning Techniques](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node396.html)

A good textbook is:

H. A. van der Vorst, *Iterative Krylov Methods for Large Linear systems*, 
Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2003.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was a bit above beginner level but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look what I have here in my bookshelves: the original thesis by Henk (H.A.) van der Vorst where it all started with , [titled](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Preconditioning_by_Incomplete_Decomposit.html?id=9Ad7NwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) : *Preconditioning by Incomplete Decompositions* (1982). If you can lay your hands on it ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Here's a famous survey paper that may be too long: [Preconditioning
  Techniques for Large Linear Systems: A Survey by Michele
  Benzi](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/survey.pdf)
- Then there's this shorter introduction that is heavy on computer
  programming and matlab:
  http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~winfried/teaching/106.079/SS2011/downloads/script-p-106-122.pdf
  It has an intimidating wall of formulas on an early page but gets
  good again later.
- Also, this link seemed mildly interesting:
  wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~botchevma/nla/

Lecture 2 has a page with simple formulas for preconditioners, and assignment 2 had a lot of work on preconditioners.

I'm not sure which famous matrices you would like to see (special lknear group, upper triangular, permutation matrix, sparse, etc.) but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and contribution, I enjoyed reading the first reference.